# Passing value from inside of function to a parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, reference

I have a function that replaces characters from a string

```
function ratko(a) {
    var k = a.toString();
    var z = k.replace(/\,/g, '], [');
    var s = z.replace(/\./g, ', ');
    var final = "[[" + s + "]]";
    alert(final);
}
```

What I need is to get the value of `final` outside the function like this:

```
var outsideValue = final;
```

EDIT!!! --

function ratko() gets it's value from ajax

success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert("Note: This month has " + data.holidays.length + " holidays.");
                praznici = data.holidays;
                ratko(praznici);
            }
            else {
                alert(data.ErrorMessage);
            }

Comment: `return final;`, then `var ousideValue = ratko(a);`?

Comment: "gets it's value from ajax". Something tells me it is yet another case of ignoring A in AJAX.

Comment: I've made jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cj4Er/

You can see the problem. I need "holiDays" to get the value of "Globalna"

Answer (score 1):

Possibility 1:

```
function ratko (a) {
   ...
   return final;
}

var outsideValue = ratko (...);
```

Possibility 2:

```
var final;
function ratko (a) {
   // no var final declaration here
   ...
}
...
ratko (...);
// now final has the value assigned to it in the function
```

You can access variables declared in an outer scope in an inner scope, which is what you do in Possibility 2.

Comment: Thank you JohnB but that does not solver my issue. I still get "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

You declare it outside the function scope:

```
  var finalVar;

function ratko(a) {
var k = a.toString();
var z = k.replace(/\,/g, '], [');
var s = z.replace(/./g, ', ');
 finalVar= "[[" + s + "]]";
alert(finalVar);
}

var outsideValue = finalVar;
```

Beware `final` is a reserved keyword in Javascript. I changed its name.
Besides that, keep in mind that Javascript is always parsed from top to bottom. So using a variable before declaring it will definitely give you an `undefined`.

Comment: What I did was this:

    var final;
    function ratko(a) {
        var k = a.toString();
        var z = k.replace(/\,/g, '], [');
        var s = z.replace(/\./g, ', ');
        final = "[[" + s + "]]";
      
    }
    var outsideValue = final;
    document.write(outsideValue);

And it gives me "undefined";

Comment: Where do you call the function?

Comment: I've made jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cj4Er/

You can see it here. What I need is "holiDays" to get the value of "Globalna"

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a global variable, just declare it outside of the function.

```
var myvar = 1;
function myFunction()
   alert(myvar); // 1
}
```

You can read more on [javascript variables here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp).

Answer (score 0):

you must be modify your function code like this

```
function ratko(a) {
  var k = a.toString();
  var z = k.replace(/\,/g, '], [');
  var s = z.replace(/./g, ', ');
  var final = "[[" + s + "]]";
  //alert(final); comment this code line and replace this with the code above
  return final;
}
```

after you can call your function `ratko` with this simple code

`var inputValue = 'simple message';`

`var parsedValue = ratko(inputValue);`

you find the `final` value into a new variable `parsedValue`

Comment: Again sir, on document.write(parsedValue) i get "undefined"

Comment: but your alert return "undefined"? in this case the problem is the function... another question is if you use the document.write under the call at the function or in another context

Comment: No, the alert giver me everything fine, but the document.write - doesn't

Comment: you use the document.write under the call at the function or in another context?

Comment: no, outside of the function. I use it for sole purpose to see if my variable gets the data.

Comment: Yes it's in the comment above yours.

Comment: but i don't see when your write the result of the function. the porblem could be that you call document write before the async call is finished